# (GCE) Ops-Agent Repeatedly Logging into PostgreSQL container

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-ops-agent

I have installed the ops-agent(Version: 2.46.1) on my GCE instance with the following primary configuration:

```
metrics:
  receivers:
    postgresql:
      type: postgresql
      username: opsagent
      password: test1234
      insecure: true
      endpoint: localhost:5432
      collection_interval: 30s
  service:
    pipelines:
      postgresql:
        receivers:
        - postgresql
```

I followed the rest of the setup according to the official documentation: [Configuring the Ops Agent for PostgreSQL](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/agents/ops-agent/third-party/postgresql#example-config).

[image]

After starting the service, I noticed that the ops-agent repeatedly logging into the PostgreSQL database container.

Is this behavior normal? Or could it potentially exhaust the database's connections and other related resources?

If it's problematic, how can I stop this behavior?

(P.S. I have already set collection_interval: 30s).

Github Issue: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ops-agent/issues/1614